# How can i by pass a string that is not a date when i'm trying to Date.parse a date?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm scraping a website and i'm trying to get the date of for example a books release date. The site does not always provide a date for each book and i would sometimes see "No date", "????", "Not yet released" and so on. How can I by pass that if i'm trying to run something like what i have below and not get an error? I can run an `if` statement but i feel that it will get messy.

```
book = page.css(".date").text
date = Date.parse(book)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic) offers robust date parsing, and will handle invalid formats like those you'll experience, as well.

You can install it with:

```
gem install chronic
```

or in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "chronic"
```

You can parse the dates from your example like so:

```
book = page.css(".date").text
date = Chronic.parse(book)
```

If the date is invalid, Chronic will return `nil`.  Then, all you have to do is ensure that your code is `nil`-aware; *any* solution that deals with invalid dates must be `nil`-aware, so this requirement is not exclusive to Chronic.

The Chronic gem hasn't been updated in a while, but it is still relevant.  It covers so much ground with date parsing that you'll be able to use it for quote some time.  For example, you may find dates in a variety of formats (e.g. '12/13/99', '2002-10-04', 'May 13, 2007'), and Chronic handles those without breaking a sweat.  The Ruby Date parser only supports a limited number of formats by default, and you have to build custom code around it to make it aware of more date formats.

In the accepted answer for [Ruby: List DateTime Format Options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37358558/6263819), I showed how to implement and use a `DateParser` class that also caches results to improve performance; this is worth a read, as it certainly helps in circumstances like this.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby we handle exceptions with `rescue`:

```
begin
  date = Date.parse("not a date")
rescue ArgumentError
  date = Date.today
end

p date
# => #<Date: 2016-05-28 ((2457537j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

In the above you could also leave the `begin` block empty, in which case `date` would be set to `nil`. Also, it's somewhat more idiomatic to move the assignment outside the block:

```
date = begin
  Date.parse("not a date")
rescue ArgumentError
  Date.today
end
```

You can also use `rescue` as a postfix or modifier expression:

```
date = Date.parse("not a date") rescue Date.today
p date
# => #<Date: 2016-05-28 ((2457537j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Use this sparingly, however, since you can't specify the exception type and so it may swallow exceptions you don't expect it to, which can make debugging hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch instead.

```
try {
    date = Date.parse(book)
}catch(e){
    // set date as the default value.
}
```